# High speed time series query postgresql hardware considerations

Tags: performance, postgresql, time-series

Just have some general questions on hardware choices for polling lots of low-medium density sensor data time series as fast as possible.

**System Overview**

The data consists of multiple time series of approx 50-100K data points from various sensors at different locations at different times. ~15 columns of data in the main table, but some columns have long array values in them. I'm interfacing with C#/python to send queries to a local database and then work on the returned data.

**The Problem and Some Thoughts**

As it stands, the logging server is on average hardware (budget 4tb hdds, basic quadcore, 8gb ram) and depending on the amount of data requested in the query, it takes forever (re: "annoying amounts of waiting") to return an entire time series. I have thousands of independent time series and I want to compare multiple ones against each other. Returning a single time series takes at least 30 for 50K rows with a * can take 30+ seconds, but as low as 100ms for only a few columns. A lot of different queries are used so I don't have the luxury of caching for repeated queries.

So what I was thinking of is, instead of work directly from the online server, make an offline copy of the database onto more dedicated hardware that can be used for faster analysis. I don't need all of the data at any one time (i.e. I can pick a a location and time range, copy that offline, and work on that)

The table design is very basic. The most often queried table data has primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY (location_id, time_logged, sensor_id)
```

With simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE location_id = 2154321 AND sensor_id = 254;
```

This is most common, and will be used along with some additional WHERE conditions.

There are thousands of location_id and potentially dozens of sensor_id for each location_id

**The Questions**

(with regard to the above table/pk/query setup)

1. How much does more RAM help with faster queries. i.e. 64GB vs 8GB
2. How much does faster cpu / more cores help with faster queries. What kind of CPU (quad/6/12+) would provide the best speedup. Is there diminishing returns?
3. How would one set up hard disk drives to help with faster queries (RAID cluster with SSD or mechanical).
4. Would getting a couple or even 4+ cheap mechanical hard disk drives provide a significant speedup in RAID?
5. I've read about columnar store and how it can be useful for time series (https://www.citusdata.com/blog/76-postgresql-columnar-store-for-analytics). Can anyone shed any insight on this and is it worth setting up?
6. Will increasing the planner statistics value help significantly?
7. Any general recommendations / first steps to get the best kind of query speedup? Another dedicated PC with multi-core and lots of ram? A NAS? Dedicated PC with multi-drive RAID

I'm relatively new to working with databases so don't really know what to expect in terms of performance so any pointers would be helpful.

thanks!

Comment: Why  `location_id, time_logged, sensor_id` and not  `location_id, time_logged, sensor_id`? Also: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: @JakubKania You mean `location_id, sensor_id` possibly?

Comment: @Patrick: Umm, yes, that. Thanks.

Comment: Why not load the data into a time-series database to take advantage of recent advancements in their design and features?

Comment: @JakubKania Wouldn't that mean one would only be able to insert a single value for every (location_id, sensor_id) and any following insertion would result in a unique_violation error? Or maybe the pk should be (location_id, sensor_id, time_logged) ?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov I'm looking into that currently. When the logging db was set up the only knowledge I had was in pgsql and it was the fastest to set up. Down the track it may be more suitable to transition to a tsdb but pg appears to be fine for now.

Comment: @Anthony: No, `location_id, sensor_id, time_logged` means you could use the index in the example query.

Comment: Consider using Cassandra for time series data. It is better suited as it stores data along one of your keys, contiguously. This means even spinning disks are very fast at range queries along the secondary key. A good starting point is this document: https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling